# Kubernetes External DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, ingress

Has anyone configured Kube's [external dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) project to use an IP other then that of the service or ingress it is creating the record for?

I'm on bare metal and I have:

(Internet) -> (HAProxy) -> (Kube cluster)

so the address I want all the DNS entries for my external services to have is the IP address of HAProxy, not one owned by kube. A *. entry could work, but if this is possible, I would prefer external-dns to take care of it.

Even better would be passing the NodePort service I create the IP address of HAProxy, then External DNS could use that.

Thanks all!

Thinking on this more, it would be better if I could have it setup a CNAME to that HAProxy, the ip could change at some point...